# Choose default type and encoding for C++ string literals at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, character-encoding, string-literals

C++11 introduced the new string literals for UTF-8, 16 and 32 with the `u8`, `u` and `U` prefixes but I have to hard code which one I want to use. I'm looking for a way to select which encoding I want to use at compile time (similar to how a typedef works).

User defined string literals don't seem to help as they work on the strings of the specified encoding.

I have seen in pre C++11 code the use of a short macro such as `L("string")` to choose between `"string"` and `L"string"` but personally I find that quite ugly.

Is it possible to neatly choose the default type and encoding or will I have to use the macro option?

Comment: Yes, you need a macro because you need to make tokens. I personally think the macro itself isn't ugly, but the need for it is.

Comment: it is not about string literals encoding, but mostly about which string type will be used by your app by default. and yes, you have no other options 'cept to use a macro (at least in compile-time)

Comment: It is also about encoding, by default `""` is an implementation defined single byte encoding not UTF-8 both of which use the `char` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the solution to this problem is to use the macros. Although [@Nadim Farhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614367/nadim-farhat) pointed out that you can do a certain amount of choosing with gcc it is by no means a portable solution.